# how to say "people who live near the sea, on the coast"

Tags: single-word-requests

How could you describe the population who lives in a seaside town?

For example, in a sentence like:

> We _________ [people who live near the sea]  love to walk on the beach even in winter.

Or something like that

Comment: I've heard "coasties".

Comment: People who live on the sea coast are **coastal people**. No need to complicate.

Comment: Simply 'seasiders' [see [M-W]. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seasider)] Blackpool FC have actually pinched the term; their nickname is 'the Seasiders'.

Answer (score 2):

(Not "single words", but it's a difficult question!).

**Coast/seaside dweller**

[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dweller) defines it as:

> dweller
>
> noun inhabitant, resident, citizen, denizen, indweller
>
> The number of city dwellers is growing.

And the definition itself gives other words for further combinations. The example in the definition shows that it can be used in the context of "city" as in "city dwellers", therefore a translation to "coast" or even "seaside" dwellers isn't too much of a stretch.

In your context:
"We, seaside-dwellers , love to walk on the beach even in winter."

Answer (score 0):

**coastal** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coastal)

> pertaining to or bordering on a coast.

As in coastal people or coastal folks.